# django-mptt not linking data together correctly

Tags: python, django, mptt

Hay, I'm using [MPTT](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/) to create some tree-like data from a model which contains conversations, and i want them to be ordered by a 'votes' field.

The model looks like this at the moment, very basic.

```
class Thread(MPTTModel):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    votes = models.IntegerField()

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by=['votes']
```

As you can see, we have a message field, and parent FK which is linked to the Thread model, and a votes.

Within my views i have this

```
threads = Thread.tree.all()
    data = {
        'threads':threads
    }
    return render_to_response("show.html",data )
```

then within my template

```
{% load mptt_tags %}

<ul class="root">
        {% recursetree d %}
            <li>
                {{ node.title }}
                {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                    <ul class="children">
                        {{ children }}
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

However, the outputted list is a a list of all the threads. None of them are linked together.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is THIS your actuhal code? Your view doesn't populate something called `d` in your context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% load mptt_tags %}
<ul class="root">
    {% recursetree nodes %}            
        <li>
            {{ node.message }}
            {% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
                <ul class="children">
                    {{ children }}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endrecursetree %}
</ul>
```

In views I have:

```
threads = Thread.tree.all()  
data = {  
    'nodes':threads  
}
return render_to_response("show.html",data )
```

In the html page I see a tree of nodes order alphabetically and with indentation.